# JPA database class methods

Tags: java, database, spring-mvc, jpa

I have a Spring application that stores Author objects using JPA. I have written my database class methods as such that there is a certain "template" used, to ensure good operation. However, I'm kind of a newbie and I'm not sure if this is always necessary or even desired. Any comments or information about best practices are welcome!

**The template**

```
    openConnection();
    EntityTransaction transaction = this.em.getTransaction();
    try {
        transaction.begin();
        //DO STUFF HERE
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if(transaction.isActive()) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        throw new DatabaseException(e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        closeConnection();
    }
```

**The entire database code**

```
public class AuthorDatabaseDerby implements AuthorDatabase {

    private static volatile AuthorDatabaseDerby uniqueInstance;
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private EntityManager em;

    public static AuthorDatabaseDerby getInstance() {
        if(uniqueInstance == null) {
            synchronized(AuthorDatabaseDerby.class) {
                if(uniqueInstance == null) {
                    uniqueInstance = new AuthorDatabaseDerby();
                }
            }
        }
        return uniqueInstance;
    }

    private AuthorDatabaseDerby() {
        this.emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("bookstore");
    }

    private void openConnection() {
        this.em = this.emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    private void closeConnection() throws DatabaseException {
        try {
            if(this.em != null) {
                this.em.close();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new DatabaseException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Author get(int id) throws DatabaseException {
        openConnection();
        EntityTransaction transaction = this.em.getTransaction();
        try {
            transaction.begin();
            Author author = this.em.find(Author.class, id);
            transaction.commit();
            return author;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if(transaction.isActive()) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            throw new DatabaseException(e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Author> getAll() throws DatabaseException {
        openConnection();
        EntityTransaction transaction = this.em.getTransaction();
        try {
            transaction.begin();
            List<Author> authors = this.em.createQuery("Select a From Author a", Author.class).getResultList();
            transaction.commit();
            return authors;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            if(transaction.isActive()) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            throw new DatabaseException(e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Author author) throws DatabaseException {
        openConnection();
        EntityTransaction transaction = this.em.getTransaction();
        try {
            transaction.begin();
            this.em.persist(author);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            if(transaction.isActive()) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            throw new DatabaseException(e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Author author) throws DatabaseException {
        openConnection();
        EntityTransaction transaction = this.em.getTransaction();
        try {
            transaction.begin();

            Author a = this.em.find(Author.class, author.getId());
            a.setBooks(author.getBooks());
            a.setDateBirth(author.getDateBirth());
            a.setDateDeceased(author.getDateDeceased());
            a.setFirstName(author.getFirstName());
            a.setId(author.getId());
            a.setLastName(author.getLastName());
            a.setNationality(author.getNationality());

            transaction.commit();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            if(transaction.isActive()) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            throw new DatabaseException(e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(int id) throws DatabaseException {
        openConnection();
        EntityTransaction transaction = this.em.getTransaction();
        try {
            transaction.begin();
            Author author = this.em.find(Author.class, id);
            this.em.remove(author);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            if(transaction.isActive()) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            throw new DatabaseException(e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws DatabaseException {
        try {
            if(this.emf != null) {
                this.emf.close();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new DatabaseException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for approval, not advice or recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use any of this code.

I'd prefer Spring transaction management to your template.  It's annotation and configuration based.

I'd use a connection pool rather than your connection class.

Why write code when you can use what's already available from Spring?  They write better code than you or I.  There's a broader user audience to find bugs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this is a school assignment and I'm supposd to decouple my business logic from the framework, so I can't use Spring transaction management.

Comment: OK.  Of course you are free to ignore anything you read here.  You asked for best practices - your code isn't one.  There's no pooling.  You might look at this as a better example that you could emulate.  You're free to look at the Spring source code and see how they thought about the design.